# Keyboard module (Import "keyboard" could not be resolved from source Pylance (reportMissingModuleSource))

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble with using keyboard module. I installed it with `pip install keyboard` but whenever I try `import keyboard` I get and `error: (module) keyboard Import "keyboard" could not be resolved from source Pylanc (ereportMissingModuleSource)`.

I tried reinstalling but nothing seems to work.

I tried reinstalling the module as well as installing a newer version of python but nothing seems to work.

Comment: try this once. let me know if the error persists. [Click Here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

There should be more than one python environment on your machine, you need to choose a ***correct*** python interpreter for vscode.

###### <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python:Select Interpreter`

[image]

**Make sure you are using an interpreter with the `keyboard` package installed.**

There are two ways: select the interpreter with the `keyboard` package installed
Or choose the interpreter you want to use and install the `keyboard` package for that interpreter

The python version you choose will be displayed in the lower right corner of vscode.

[image]

*You can check output current interpreter path with*

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```